# Ruby RoR get keys and values from hash separately

Tags: arrays, ruby, axlsx, ruby-hash

I have a hash like this:

```
hash = {"str1"=>5, "str2"=>9, "str3"=> 3}
```

`hash.keys` gives as a result  `["str1", "str2", "str3"]`

`hash.values` gives as a result   `[5, 9, 3]`

I'm trying to export this to excel with `Axlsx` using `sheet.add_row`

```
sheet.add_row [hash.keys[0], hash.values[0]]  # hash.keys[0] = "str1" and  hash.values[0] = 5
sheet.add_row [hash.keys[1], hash.values[1]]  # hash.keys[1] = "str2" and  hash.values[1] = 9
sheet.add_row [hash.keys[2], hash.values[2]]  # hash.keys[2] = "str3" and  hash.values[2] = 3
```

In an Excel sheet, this is the result

[image: str]

This is simple if the hash is not big but if it's composed of 20 elements or more for example, doing this this way is not pratical at all !! 
I want to do this for all the elements of the hash in a better way.

```
sheet.add_row [hash.keys[0], hash.values[0]]  
sheet.add_row [hash.keys[1], hash.values[1]] 
sheet.add_row [hash.keys[2], hash.values[2]] 
........
sheet.add_row [hash.keys[19], hash.values[19]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [Hash#`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-each) to iterate over each key-value pair:

```
hash = {"str1"=>5, "str2"=>9, "str3"=> 3}
hash.each { |k, v| sheet.add_row [k, v] }
```

Comment: It says for me `undefined method each' for nil:NilClass` that's why I tried to seperate keys and values so I can use the `each` method

Comment: @media the error means that `hash` is `nil`, nothing more. Double check.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey Deineko, it's working ! (it was just a typing error from me)

Comment: @media yep, no probs.